# WCF enabling TLS programatically using Credentials and IIS

Tags: c#, wcf, ssl, credentials

I'm developing a service to use SSL/TLS credential based security in WCF.  The endpoint will be hit using IIS and HTTPS.  A basic HTTP binding works fine, but as soon as I try to add credentials I keep getting configuration errors.  I've spent a few days on this and I've read a lot of articles but without success.

I've tried

// Code behind

```cs
    public class specificService : myServiceType
    {
        public static void Configure(ServiceConfiguration configuration)
        {
            // define https binding (I think it should be BasicHttpsBinding as opposed to BasicHttpBinding which also supports TLS but I am unsure)
            var httpsBinding = new BasicHttpsBinding
            {
                MaxReceivedMessageSize = int.MaxValue,
                Security = new BasicHttpsSecurity
                {
                    Mode = BasicHttpsSecurityMode.Transport,
                    Transport = new HttpTransportSecurity
                    {
                        ClientCredentialType = HttpClientCredentialType.Certificate
                    }
                }
            };

            configuration.AddServiceEndpoint(typeof(myServiceType), httpsBinding, string.Empty);
              configuration.Description.Endpoints.Find(typeof(myServiceType))?.EndpointBehaviors.Add(new myNamespace.MyCustomEndpointBehavior());
            configuration.Description.Behaviors.Add(new ServiceDebugBehavior { IncludeExceptionDetailInFaults = true });
            configuration.Description.Behaviors.Add(new ServiceMetadataBehavior { HttpGetEnabled = true });


            // Do I need to explicitly add my certificate?
            X509Certificate2 myCert = ... get cert from local machine store
            configuration.Credentials.ServiceCertificate.Certificate = myCert;
        }


/* myServiceType interface */
    [System.CodeDom.Compiler.GeneratedCodeAttribute("System.ServiceModel", "4.0.0.0")]
    [System.ServiceModel.ServiceContractAttribute(Namespace="http://somenamespace", ConfigurationName="someothernamespace.Services.myServiceType")]
    public interface myServiceType
    {
        // CODEGEN: Generating message contract since the operation specificAction is neither RPC nor document wrapped.
        [System.ServiceModel.OperationContractAttribute(Action="http://somenamespace/specificAction")]
        someothernamespace.Services.specificActionResponse specificAction(someothernamespace.Services.specificAction request);
    }
```

I keep getting "Configuration errors" without much detail on what exactly I'm doing wrong.  I've experimented with different implementations (wsHttpBindings) without success.

Comment: I don't know what your specific problem is, but my advice would be to try and make it work first with a configuration file. Once you have that you can use that pretty much as a template for how to do it in pure code.

Answer (score 0):

Although WCF4.5 announce that we could set up the service by using static Configure method in the service implement class, I suggest you configure the service in the configuration file. It is concise and clear.

> // Do I need to explicitly add my certificate?

You don’t need set up a certificate since the transport security mode requires a https base address in IIS site binding module.
Besides, if you want to authenticate the client with a certificate, please refer to the below link.
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/wcf/feature-details/transport-security-with-certificate-authentication
We should establish the trust relationship between the server and the client at the beginning, and then the client should provide the certificate trusted by the server. Since the Makecert command line is out of date, I recommend that you create a self-signed certificate using PowerShell and make sure that the client and server run-time environment is above dotnetframwork4.6.2.
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/pkiclient/new-selfsignedcertificate?view=win10-ps
https://github.com/dotnet/docs/issues/12000
Feel free to let me know if there is anything I can help with.